# A Functional-Imperative Hybrid

Tags: functional-programming, state, purely-functional, imperative

Pure functional programming languages do not allow mutable data, but some computations are more naturally/intuitively expressed in an imperative way -- or an imperative version of an algorithm may be more efficient.  I am aware that most functional languages are not pure, and let you assign/reassign variables and do imperative things but generally discourage it.

My question is, why not allow local state to be manipulated in local variables, but require that functions can only access their own locals and global constants (or just constants defined in an outer scope)?  That way, all functions maintain referential transparency (they always give the same return value given the same arguments), but within a function, a computation can be expressed in imperative terms (like, say, a while loop).

IO and such could still be accomplished in the normal functional ways - through monads or passing around a "world" or "universe" token.

Comment: Consider looking at existing languages including SML and Clojure.

Comment: The "local state" you're talking about reminds me of Haskell's ST monad. Also of note are uniqueness types of Clean or linear types of ATS, which also allow you to have mutability and safe reclamation of memory and other resources at the cost of imposing a rigid structure upon a program. Clean's uniqueness typing preserves referential transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: there are systems to allow what you want. For example, you can do it using the `ST` monad in Haskell (as referenced in the comments).

The `ST` monad approach is from Haskell's `Control.Monad.ST`. Code written in the `ST` monad can use references (`STRef`) where convenient. The nice part is that you can even use the results of the `ST` monad in pure code, as it is essentially self-contained (this is basically what you were wanting in the question).

The proof of this self-contained property is done through the type-system. The `ST` monad carries a state-thread parameter, usually denoted with a type-variable `s`. When you have such a computation you'll have monadic result, with a type like:

```
foo :: ST s Int
```

To actually turn this into a pure result, you have to use

```
runST :: (forall s . ST s a) -> a
```

You can read this type like: give me a computation where the `s` type parameter doesn't matter, and I can give you back the result of the computation, without the `ST` baggage. This basically keeps the mutable `ST` variables from escaping, as they would carry the `s` with them, which would be caught by the type system.

This can be used to good effect on pure structures that are implemented with underlying mutable structures (like the [vector package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1)). One can cast off the immutability for a limited time to do something that mutates the underlying array in place. For example, one could combine the immutable `Vector` with an [impure algorithms package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms-0.5.4) to keep the most of the performance characteristics of the in place sorting algorithms and still get purity.

In this case it would look something like:

```
pureSort :: Ord a => Vector a -> Vector a
pureSort vector = runST $ do
  mutableVector <- thaw vector
  sort mutableVector
  freeze mutableVector
```

The `thaw` and `freeze` functions are linear-time copying, but this won't disrupt the overall O(n lg n) running time. You can even use `unsafeFreeze` to avoid another linear traversal, as the mutable vector isn't used again.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, why not allow local state to be manipulated in local variables, but require that functions can only access their own locals and global constants (or just constants defined in an outer scope)?

Good question. I think the answer is that mutable locals are of limited practical value but mutable heap-allocated data structures (primarily arrays) are enormously valuable and form the backbone of many important collections including efficient stacks, queues, sets and dictionaries. So restricting mutation to locals only would not give an otherwise purely functional language any of the important benefits of mutation.

On a related note, communicating sequential processes exchanging purely functional data structures offer many of the benefits of both worlds because the sequential processes can use mutation internally, e.g. mutable message queues are ~10x faster than any purely functional queues. For example, this is idiomatic in F# where the code in a `MailboxProcessor` uses mutable data structures but the messages communicated between them are immutable.

Sorting is a good case study in this context. Sedgewick's quicksort in C is short and simple and hundreds of times faster than the fastest purely functional sort in any language. The reason is that quicksort mutates the array in-place. Mutable locals would not help. Same story for most graph algorithms.

Comment: A nitpick: It seems like mutable locals actually would help with quicksort.  An implementation could copy the input data (stored in some immutable sequence) into a local mutable array, run the quicksort algorithm on that local, and then copy the result into an immutable sequence and return it.  (That said, because quicksort is most naturally implemented via recursion, running quicksort on the local might require the ability to define recursive functions where that mutable local is in scope, or where it is passed as a parameter, which might be a bit of a tricky PL design challenge.)

Answer (score 0):

"Pure functional programming languages do not allow mutable data" ... actually it does, you just simply have to recognize where it lies hidden and see it for what it is.

Mutability is where two things have the same name and mutually exclusive times of existence so that they may be treated as "the same thing at different times". But as every Zen philosopher knows, there is no such thing as "same thing at different times". Everything ceases to exist in an instant and is inherited by its successor in possibly changed form, in a (possibly) uncountably-infinite succession of instants.

In the lambda calculus, mutability thus takes the form illustrated by the following example: (λx (λx f(x)) (x+1)) (x+1), which may also be rendered as "let x = x + 1 in let x = x + 1 in f(x)" or just "x = x + 1, x = x + 1, f(x)" in a more C-like notation.

In other words, "name clash" of the "lambda calculus" is actually "update" of imperative programming, in disguise. They are one and the same - in the eyes of the Zen (who is always right).

So, let's refer to each instant and state of the variable as the Zen Scope of an object. One ordinary scope with a mutable object equals many Zen Scopes with constant, unmutable objects that either get initialized if they are the first, or inherit from their predecessor if they are not.

When people say "mutability" they're misidentifying and confusing the issue. Mutability (as we've just seen here) is a complete red herring. What they *actually* mean (even unbeknonwst to themselves) is *infinite* mutability; i.e. the kind which occurs in *cyclic* control flow structures. In other words, what they're actually referring to - as being specifically "imperative" and not "functional" - is not mutability at all, but cyclic control flow structures along with the infinite nesting of Zen Scopes that this entails.

The key feature that lies absent in the lambda calculus is, thus, seen not as something that may be remedied by the inclusion of an overwrought and overthought "solution" like monads (though that doesn't exclude the possibility of it getting the job done) but as *infinitary terms*.

A control flow structure is the wrapping of an unwrapped (possibility infinite) decision tree structure. Branches may re-converge. In the corresponding unwrapped structure, they appear as replicated, but separate, branches or subtrees. Goto's are direct links to subtrees. A goto or branch that back-branches to an earlier part of a control flow structure (the very genesis of the "cycling" of a cyclic control flow structure) is a link to an identically-shaped copy of the entire structure being linked to. Corresponding to each structure is its Universally Unrolled decision tree.

More precisely, we may think of a control-flow structure as a statement that precedes an actual expression that conditions the value of that expression. The archetypical case in point is Landin's original case, itself (in his 1960's paper, where he tried to lambda-ize imperative languages): let x = 1 in f(x). The "x = 1" part is the statement, the "f(x)" is the value being conditioned by the statement. In C-like form, we could write this as x = 1, f(x).

More generally, corresponding to each statement S and expression Q is an expression S[Q] which represents the result Q after S is applied. Thus, (x = 1)[f(x)] is just λx f(x) (x + 1). The S wraps around the Q. If S contains cyclic control flow structures, the wrapping will be infinitary.

When Landin tried to work out this strategy, he hit a hard wall when he got to the while loop and went "Oops. Never mind." and fell back into what become an overwrought and overthought solution, while this simple (and in retrospect, obvious) answer eluded his notice.

A while loop "while (x < n) x = x + 1;" - which has the "infinite mutability" mentioned above, may itself be treated as an infinitary wrapper, "if (x < n) { x = x + 1; if (x < 1) { x = x + 1; if (x < 1) { x = x + 1; ... } } }". So, when it wraps around an expression Q, the result is (in C-like notation) "x < n? (x = x + 1, x < n? (x = x + 1, x < n? (x = x + 1, ...): Q): Q): Q", which may be *directly* rendered in lambda form as "x < n? (λx x < n (λx x < n? (λx·...) (x + 1): Q) (x + 1): Q) (x + 1): Q". This shows directly the connection between cyclicity and infinitariness.

This is an infinitary expression that, despite being infinite, has only a finite number of distinct subexpressions. Just as we can think of there being a Universally Unrolled form to this expression - which is similar to what's shown above (an infinite decision tree) - we can also think of there being a Maximally Rolled form, which could be obtained by labelling each of the distinct subexpressions and referring to the labels, instead. The key subexpressions would then be:

A: x < n? goto B: Q

B: x = x + 1, goto A

The subexpression labels, here, are "A:" and "B:", while the references to the subexpressions so labelled as "goto A" and "goto B", respectively. So, by magic, the very essence of Imperativitity emerges directly out of the infinitary lambda calculus, without any need to posit it separately or anew.

This way of viewing things applies even down to the level of binary files. Every interpretation of every byte (whether it be a part of an opcode of an instruction that starts 0, 1, 2 or more bytes back, or as part of a data structure) can be treated as being there in tandem, so that the binary file is a rolling up of a much larger universally unrolled structure whose physical byte code representation overlaps extensively with itself.

Thus, emerges the imperative programming language paradigm automatically out of the pure lambda calculus, itself, when the calculus is extended to include infinitary terms. The control flow structure is *directly* embodied in the very structure of the infinitary expression, itself; and thus requires no additional hacks (like Landin's or later descendants, like monads) - as it's already there.

This synthesis of the imperative and functional paradigms arose in the late 1980's via the USENET, but has not (yet) been published. Part of it was already implicit in the treatment (dating from around the same time) given to languages, like Prolog-II, and the much earlier treatment of cyclic recursive structures by infinitary expressions by Irene Guessarian LNCS 99 "Algebraic Semantics".

Now, earlier I said that the magma-based formulation *might* get you to the same place, or to an approximation thereof. I believe there is a kind of universal representation theorem of some sort, which asserts that the infinitary based formulation provides a *purely syntactic* representation, and that the semantics that arise from the monad-based representation factors through this as "monad-based semantics" = "infinitary lambda calculus" + "semantics of infinitary languages".

Likewise, we may think of the "Q" expressions above as being continuations; so there may also be a universal representation theorem for continuation semantics, which similarly rolls this formulation back into the infinitary lambda calculus.

At this point, I've said nothing about *non-rational* infinitary terms (i.e. infinitary terms which possess an infinite number of distinct subterms and no finite Minimal Rolling) - particularly in relation to interprocedural control flow semantics. Rational terms suffice to account for loops and branches, and so provide a platform for intraprocedural control flow semantics; but not as much so for the call-return semantics that are the essential core element of interprocedural control flow semantics, if you consider subprograms to be directly represented as embellished, glorified macros.

There may be something similar to the Chomsky hierarchy for infinitary term languages; so that type 3 corresponds to rational terms, type 2 to "algebraic terms" (those that can be rolled up into a finite set of "goto" references and "macro" definitions), and type 0 for "transcendental terms". That is, for me, an unresolved loose end, as well.